# hashMap<String,AddressBO> in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have hashmap `<< String, AddressBO >>` string `key` and class as `value`,where `AddressBO` is a class that has `add1`,`add2`,`city`,`state`,`zip` etc fields,and in map i have just two keys-primary and secondary and there value is object of `AddressBO`. Now I have to compare whether address are same or different ie values are same for both the object. For this do I have to override equals and `hashcode` method in `AddressBo` class or `implement comparator interface`?

Comment: You can try both solutions. It will work.

Comment: The values arent hashed, only the keys, so overriding hashcode is pretty useless. Whether you create an equals or compareTo method or make a comparator, doesnt matter, they all will work.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with `HashMap`, it's more just "how do I compare objects in java".  Yes, you need to override `equals` if you want to do anything that not simply reference matching.  Additionally, if you override `equals`, you should also override `hashCode` to maintain the contract between `equals` and `hashCode`.  While the `hashCode` doesn't matter for the `HashMap` where your objects are the values, it could matter if you ever try to use your objects as keys for another `HashMap`.  Overriding `compareTo` is something that you should do if you intend for your object to be put in some structure that will potentially sort it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparable` interface is intended for sorting, not for equality testing. Of course, if two objects are logically equal you should get `a.compareTo(b)=b.compareTo(a)=0`, but the other way round is not always true. Suppose you want to sort a list of people alphabetically by surname and given name. Two people called John Doe, one born in 1956 and one in 1996 could be listed in any order - but they are not the same person.

If you want to test two objects for equality, implement `equals(Object)` (and `hashCode()`, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two objects of a class, the class should implement the `comparable` interface.  You should also override hashcode and equals (even if you do not expect to use those functions ... because things may change in the future and you might as well implement while you still understand what is going on within your complex object)

If you look at the definition of `equals()` ("javadoc for the java language), you will note that it must define an equality relation (reflexive, symmetric, and transitive) and checking `equals(null)` should always return null.

Likewise, `hashCode()` must also be consistent (returning the same value for all objects that match `equals()`